# Regular expression for no more than two repeated letters/digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to handle a regular expression for no more than two of the same letters/digits in an XSL file.

- no space
- does not support special chars
- support (a-z,A-Z,0-9)
- require one of a-z
- require one of 0-9
- no more than 2 same letter/digits (i.e., `BBB` will fail, `BB` is accepted)

What I have so far

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2})
```

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a regular expression, or could a function that returns true or false be OK?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I have a function to check to see if the the variable match the regex. which return true or false

Comment: @HamZa : AABAA is accepted, as long as not 3 consecutive

Comment: so at least one lowercase letter and one digit is required? should the string also start with a (lowercase) letter or doesn't that matter?

Comment: @rednaw: does not matter, as long as the regex meet all the requirment

Answer (score 32):

This regex will do it:
`^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

Here's the breakdown:

`(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})` makes sure that none of the chars repeat more than twice in a row.

`(?=.*[a-z])` requires at least one lowercase letter

`(?=.*\d)` requires at least one digit

`[A-Za-z0-9]+` allows only letters and digits

**EDIT :**
removed an extraneous `.*` from the negative lookahead

Comment: I'm testing the regex and it isn't matching strings like `A1D3E` (valid) or `AAAA` (invalid).

Comment: @Rasco: lowercase letter is required, so `A1D3E` is invalid.

Comment: @Brian Stephens, this works fine as now, I've tested serveral case, need further testing too

Comment: @cool_spirit is a lowercase letter required as Brian said? Because earlier you said `AABAA` would be valid

Comment: @rednaw, you're right that he said `AABAA` is valid, but that contradicts the other requirement that a digit is required too. I think he meant the `AABAA` example just to clarify the repetition requirement only. Confusing!

Comment: +1 for explaining the regex. So many regex answers don't do that, and it's hard to work out what's going on.

Comment: `(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[a-z]).{5,}`

how can I make it pass (I use it for validation) if the repeated characters are part of a string? (e.g. "includes AAA batteries" as a row should pass my validation)

Comment: @Angelo: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but this regex is to **prevent** more than two repeated characters, so "AAA" should fail. If you have a different scenario, you may want to post a new question.

Answer (score 26):

(Partial solution) For matching the same character repeated 3 or more times consecutively, try:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{2,}
```

Sample matches (tested both [here](http://www.myregextester.com/) and [here](http://www.regexpal.com/)): `AABBAA` (no matches), `AABBBAAA` (matches `BBB` and `AAA`), `ABABABABABABABA` (no matches), `ABCCCCCCCCCC` (matches `CCCCCCCCCC`).

Comment: Was just about to post this! Beat me to it!

Comment: this doesn't require at least one digit and one char

Comment: I agree. This solution doesn't require at least one digit and one char, doesn't limit to alphanumeric, and is the opposite of what he's trying to match. See my answer, which satisfies all the requirements.

Comment: I changed the answer so it's clear that it addresses one of the requirements.

Comment: I believe the 3 was accidentally switched from a 9.
```([a-zA-Z0-3])\1{2,}``` should probably be ```([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{2,}```

Comment: Can anyone please explain why `{2,}` and not `{3,}`?

Comment: @pkout Because the group (the part in parentheses) already matched the character the first time. You need it to be repeated at least two more times. Just in case, double-check that you saw the \1 in the pattern. It's critical.

Comment: @Racso, makes sense. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Does this one work for you?

```
/(\b(?:([A-Za-z0-9])(?!\2{2}))+\b)/
```

Try it out:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(\b(?:([A-Za-z0-9])(?!\2{2}))+\b)/)
var tests = ['A1D3E', 'AAAA', 'AABAA', 'abccddeeff', 'abbbc', '1234']

for(test in tests) {
   console.log(tests[test] + ' - ' + Boolean(tests[test].match(regex)))
}
```

Will output:

```
A1D3E - true
AAAA - false
AABAA - true
abccddeeff - true
abbbc - false
1234 - true
```

Comment: Upvoting,... It though it doesn't meet the requirements of the OP, it does meet the requirements I have, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You may do this in 2 regexes:

1. `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]+$/i` This will assure that there is at least 1 digit and 1 letter while accepting only letters and digits (no space or special characters)
2. `/([a-z0-9])\1{2,}/i` If this one is matched, then there is a repeated character. Which means you should throw `false`.

## Explanation:

**First regex:**

- `^` : match begin of line
- `(?=.*[a-z])` : check if there is at least one letter
- `(?=.*[0-9])` : check if there is at least one digit
- `[a-z0-9]+` : if the checks were true, then match only digits/letters one or more times
- `$` : match end of line
- `i` : modifier, match case insensitive

**Second regex:**

- `([a-z0-9])` : match and group a digit or a letter
- `\1{2,}` : match group 1 two or more times
- `i` : modifier, match case insensitive

Comment: somehow, xsl file doesnot really like /, I dont know why

Comment: @cool_spirit Then use `(?i)^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]+$` and `(?i)([a-z0-9])\1{2,}` instead. I assumed that this is pure JS...

Answer (score 1):

In response to a clarification, it seems that a single regular expression isn't strictly required. In that case I suggest you use several regular expressions or functions. My guess is, performance isn't a requirement, since usually these sorts of checks are done in response to user input. User input validation can take 100ms and still appear to be instant, and you can run a *lot* of code in 100ms.

For example, I personally would do a check for each of your conditions in a separate test. First, check for spaces. Second, check for at least one letter. Next, check for at least one number. Finally, look for any spans of three or more repeated characters.

Your code will be much easier to understand, and it will be much easier to modify the rules later (which, experience has shown, is almost certainly going to happen).

For example:

```
function do_validation(string) {
    return (has_no_space(string) &&
            has_no_special_char(string) &&
            has_alpha(string) &&
            has_digit(string) &&
            ! (has_repeating(string)))
```

I personally consider the above to be orders of magnitude easier to read than one complex regular expression. Plus, adding or removing a rule doesn't make you have to reimplement a complex regular expression (and thus, be required to re-test all possible combinations).

Comment: again, thanks, but how I handle now is using different to approach, dont want to construct my file a lot