# Regex [4 characters, one letter, Cannot be all the same character]

Tags: regex

Requirements:
Must be more than 4 characters
Must contain at least one letter a-zA-Z
Cannot be all the same character (regardless of length)

based on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973233/regular-expression-for-no-more-than-2-repeated-letters-digits/17973873#17973873) I came up with:

```
(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[a-z]).{5,}
```

and it works fine not matching values like "aaaaa".

`(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})` makes sure that none of the chars repeat more than twice in a row.

`(?=.*[a-z])` requires at least one lowercase letter

The problem is I need the "row" to be valid (I use the regex for validation purposes) if the word with repeated characters is part of a sentence (not on his own) e.g. "includes AAA batteries".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to remove the ".*" expression from the first negative look-ahead:

```
(?!([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[a-z]).{5,}
```

This now matches: *hello AAAAA test* or *includes AAA batteries*

But it still does not match: *AAAAA*

Edit:

If you want to support also expressions like *AAAAA batteries*, you should actually use:

```
(?!([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2}$)(?=.*[a-z]).{5,}
```

Credits go to @Brian Stephens on this correction.

Comment: This doesn't meet all the OP's requirements. It will consider "AAA batteries" as invalid, when he wanted it to be valid. You need a "$" anchor in the negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex is what you need:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{1}).{4,}
```

To explain it a bit:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])             // To make sure there is at least one letter (uppercase or lower case)
(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})   // To make sure nothing will repeat twice in a row
.{4,}                      // Have at least 4 characters
```

This regex will allow things like

```
aa23
A123
a1234
A1234
$%$%a
$%$%A
```

To exclude 'weird' characters you'll need to add `(?!.*[\W])` like so:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*[\W])(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{1}).{4,}
```